# django gunicorn app spams the console with "Not Found: /api/templates/menu_main/" every second or so

Tags: python, django, docker, gunicorn

I've built a simple django app and I'm working on dockerizing it.  I'm able to create the image and start it.  It even works fine locally via "docker run -it -p 8000:8000 project:0.1".  However, the project logs this message to the console about every seconds or so:

Not Found: /api/templates/menu_main/

I don't have a rest api or anything in the app, just a couple tables and several views.

Here's requirements.txt:

```
beautifulsoup4==4.8.2
certifi==2019.11.28
chardet==3.0.4
Django==2.0.7
django-auth-ldap==2.1.0
django-background-tasks==1.2.5
django-bootstrap4==1.1.1
django-compat==1.0.15
django-phone-field==1.8.0
gunicorn==20.0.4
idna==2.9
mysqlclient==1.4.6
psycopg2==2.8.4
pyasn1==0.4.8
pyasn1-modules==0.2.8
PyJWT==1.7.1
python-ldap==3.2.0
pytz==2019.3
requests==2.23.0
six==1.14.0
soupsieve==2.0
twilio==6.36.0
urllib3==1.25.8
whitenoise==5.0.1
```

Googling for the error message didn't reveal anything that I could act on.

Any idea what the message means?  How do I stop it from filling up the logs?

Thank you!

Comment: Please kindly post the actual code so the community can understand what you are trying to do. `requirements.txt` does not help since it only specifies dependencies.

Comment: What code would you like to see exactly?